# Tensorflow 2 -Keras SAVE/LOAD model error (DenseFeatures and DistributionLambda layers)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow-probability

I have a Tensorflow 2.x model which is using the TF preprocessing layer (tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures) and the distributional layer from TF probability (DistributionLambda):

```py
def regression_deep1_proba2(preprocessing_layer, feature_layer_inputs, model_name='test_model'):


    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        preprocessing_layer,
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', name='hidden_1'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu', name='hidden_2'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1 + 1, name='output'),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
            lambda t: tfd.LogNormal(loc=t[..., :1], scale=tf.math.softplus(0.05 * t[..., 1:]))
        ),
    ])

    # ____________________ COMPILE WITH  ____________________________________________
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    negloglik = lambda y, p_y: -p_y.log_prob(y)

    metrics = [
        tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsolutePercentageError()
        ]

    model.compile(
        loss=negloglik,
        optimizer=optimizer,
        metrics=metrics
    )

    # ____________________ CALLBACKS DEFINITION ___________________________________________
    tbCallBack = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
        log_dir=f'./logs_regression/{model_name}',
        update_freq='batch',
        histogram_freq=1,
        embeddings_freq=1,
        write_graph=True,
        write_images=True
    )

    # Create a callback that saves the model's weights every 5 epochs
    cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath=f'./weights.{model_name}.hdf5',
        verbose=1,
        save_weights_only=True,
        save_best_onlt=True,
        monitor='MeanSquaredError'
    )
    early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor='MeanSquaredError',
        patience=2
    )
    callbacks_list = [tbCallBack, cp_callback, early_stop]

    return model, callbacks_list
```

I can get some nice results for the regression problem with this model, but when I save it for further use I can't load it back anymore (I have tried all online tutorials and solutions, but nothing is working)!!

I get different types of errors depending on how do I save tahat model, but in general I have:

when using:

```py
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, 'model_name.h5')
```

on

```py
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model_name.h5')
```

I get:

```py
ValueError: ('We expected a dictionary here. Instead we got: ', <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>)
```

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong - any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 3):

Can't remember where I stumbled upon this but the soultion in my case was to save the model without '.h5' extention in the model name

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, "model_name")
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model_name")
```

Comment: I have tried all possible combinations: h5, tf, Jason, simple weights and other formats but none of them does work ... I have even tried in different systems: Mac, Ubuntu and on different Tensorflow versions: 2 and 2.1 ...   Of course, all the saving and loading (different ways) works great for all models without the TF Probability layer (even with a DenseFeatures layer)

Answer (score 3):

For Tensorflow probability models currently only loading weights work. The callback is also only saving weights. Therefore to load the model first define the model architecture and then load weights.

```
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        preprocessing_layer,
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', name='hidden_1'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu', name='hidden_2'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1 + 1, name='output'),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
            lambda t: tfd.LogNormal(loc=t[..., :1], scale=tf.math.softplus(0.05 * t[..., 1:]))
        ),
    ])

model.load_weights(model_path)
#Predict using Model (Currently model.predict() will not work given distribution Lamba output layer)
model(new_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created an issue on Tensorflow probability issues github:

https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/755